# Synchronized cloud storage that allows sync to be toggled ON/OFF at the subfolder level

Tags: file-synchronization, cloud-storage

I am looking for cloud storage that has a desktop app where the sync can be toggled ON/OFF at the subfolder level, for example:

```
c:
  users
     me
       cloud  [everything in this folder is synchronized by default]
          projects
              project1
                  foo.txt
                  anothersubfolder
```

I would like to be able to toggle sync OFF/ON for folder `project1` (recursively to include all of its subfolders and files).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with AJC Sync - I am the author. This is sync/backup software that can work with multiple cloud providers like Dropbox, OneDrive, GoogleDrive etc. It can sync your files direct to the cloud rather than using the software provided by those providers.

In the AJC sync project you get much better control and you can include/exclude sub folders. You can do this by going to the Explorer tab and checking/unchecking the boxes against files/folders. You also get much more flexibility because you can have multiple projects and sync to different folders etc. Plus you get a built in diff so you can see what has changed etc

Read more about [AJC Sync](http://www.ajcsoft.com/file-sync.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Since the only answer is promoting a paid solution, I'll add an answer despite the age of this question.
[Seafile can do that](https://www.seafile.com/en/help/ignore/). 
Seafile is hostable for free (even the pro version is free for 3 users).
And there are some providers where you can use a hosted seafile instance.
Seafile itself promotes [datamate.com](https://www.datamate.org/seafile) as primary partner.